# How to control player movement in code (event handlers, PATCH, change direction, control player location with x,y)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to complete a lab, however I cannot seem to figure out how to manipulate and control player movement in my maze game. The code contains several TODOs which I cannot figure out how to do. If any extra information is required in my question please tell me before down-voting, thanks. The code is as follows:

```
function turnLeft() {
    // TODO implement this event handlerA
    // change the player's direction as appropriate
    switch (player.dir) {
      case "north": player.dir = "west";
      case "east": player.dir = "north";
      case "west": player.dir = "south";
      case "south": player.dir = "east";
      // fill in remaining directions...
    }
    // and PATCH the player with the new direction
    // (note that PATCHing the Player model is not yet implemented in the controller
    // ...

    // finally, be sure to render the room again to update the view
    renderRoom(room);
  }

  function turnRight() {
    // TODO implement this event handler
    // much like you did for turnLeft
  }

  function turnAround() {
    // TODO implement this event handler
    // much like you did for turnLeft and turnRight
  }

  function moveFwd() {
    // TODO implement this event handler
    // depending on which direction the player is facing...
    // determine whether or not there is a wall...
    // if there is a wall, then pop up an alert saying you can't go that way
    // and if there is no wall...
    // then increment/decrement the player's x or y coordinate as appropriate
    // and PATCH the player with the new location
    // finally, be sure to render the room again to update the view

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the player a div? If so, every time you move it, delete the current one and build a new one. It's not super efficient, but it's how I know to do this.

Comment: Then sorry, I haven't worked enough with that to help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For future reference, its better to seek clarification via a comment, rather than post a possibly incorrect answer.